# Formulario em Html

Tags: html

Estou tentando criar um formulario de contato em html, mas quando eu mando enviar, ele abre o outlook e desconfigura as informações. Como eu faço? O formulario será incluido dentro de um ecommerce.

```
<form action="mailto:contato@aquelux.com.br" method="post">
<p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Equipamento*</span></p>
<input name="size" type="radio" value="Solar Banho" />Aquecedor Solar Banho<br />
<input name="size" type="radio" value="Solar Piscina" />Aquecedor Solar Piscina<br />
<input name="size" type="radio" value="Solar Piscina" />Aquecimento a Gas<br />
<input name="size" type="radio" value="Solar Piscina" />Energia Solar Fotovoltaica<br />
<input name="size" type="radio" value="Solar Piscina" />Equipamentos para Piscina
<p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Nome*</span></p>

<p><input maxlength="100" name="Nome1" size="100" type="text" value=" " /></p>

<p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">E-mail*</span></p>

<p><input maxlength="100" name="Nome1" size="100" type="text" value=" " /></p>

<p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Cidade/Estado*</span></p>

<p><input maxlength="100" name="Nome1" size="100" type="text" value=" " /></p>

<p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Telefone*</span></p>

<p><input maxlength="100" name="Nome1" size="100" type="text" value=" " /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Email Yourself" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Apenas definir o `action` como `mailto` não faz enviar o e-mail. Você precisará fazer isso manualmente com alguma linguagem de programação (ou serviço de terceiro).

Comment: vc poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link, Paula:
https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/12811-formulario-de-contato-em-php

Answer (score 2):

O protocolo `mailto` é um tipo especial de URL que abre o aplicativo padrão de e-mails do dispositivo do usuário.

A mensagem estava "desconfigurada" porque não foram passados os parâmetros para a URL. São basicamente dois: `subject` (assunto da mensagem) e `body` (corpo da mensagem). A URL tem o seguinte formato (retirei desse link: [Link de compartilhamento por e-mail](https://www.blogcyberini.com/2018/08/botao-para-compartilhamento-de-conteudo-email.html))

> `mailto:[E-MAIL]?subject=[ASSUNTO]&body=[CORPO-DA-MENSAGEM]`

Se o seu objetivo é que o formulário de contato abra o aplicativo de e-mail padrão do usuário, então você pode seguir uma abordagem como a do HTML a seguir (eu basicamente modifiquei o seu código), que obtém os valores do campo via JavaScript, preenche a URL `mailto` e a abre utilizando a função `window.open(url, target)`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function submitForm(){
            var mailtoURL = "mailto:contato@aquelux.com.br?"; //URL do protocolo mailto

            //obtém o equipamento
            var equipamento = document.querySelector("#contato input[name='size']:checked").value;

            //obtém o nome
            var nome = document.querySelector("#contato input[name='Nome1']").value;

            //obtém o valor do campo Cidade/Estado
            var cidadeUf = document.querySelector("#contato input[name='cidade-uf']").value;

            //obtém o e-mail do remetente
            var emailremetente = document.querySelector("#contato input[name='mail']").value;

            //obtém o telefone
            var telefone = document.querySelector("#contato input[name='telefone']").value;

            //o assunto da mensagem é o nome do equipamento (você pode mudar)
            var assunto = encodeURIComponent(equipamento);

            //corpo da mensagem: contém nome, cidade/estado, telefone e e-mail do remetente
            var corpoMgs = encodeURIComponent("Nome: " + nome) + '%0D%0A';
            corpoMgs += encodeURIComponent("Cidade/Estado: " + cidadeUf) + '%0D%0A';
            corpoMgs += encodeURIComponent("Telefone: " + telefone) + '%0D%0A';
            corpoMgs += encodeURIComponent("e-mail: " + emailremetente);

            //acrescenta o corpo da mensagem e o assunto à URL do mailto
            mailtoURL += "subject="+assunto+"&body="+corpoMgs;

            //abre uma nova guia/janela com a url (isso vai abrir o aplicativo padrão de e-mails)
            window.open(mailtoURL, '_black');
        }        
    </script>
    <form id="contato" onsubmit="submitForm()">
        <p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Equipamento*</span></p>
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="Solar Banho" checked />Aquecedor Solar Banho<br />
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="Solar Piscina" />Aquecedor Solar Piscina<br />
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="Aquecimento a Gás" />Aquecimento a Gás<br />
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="Energia Solar Fotovoltaica" />Energia Solar Fotovoltaica<br />
        <input name="size" type="radio" value="Equipamentos para Piscina" />Equipamentos para Piscina
        <p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Nome*</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="Nome1" size="100" type="text" value=" " /></p>
        <p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">E-mail*</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="mail" size="100" type="text" value=" " /></p>
        <p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Cidade/Estado*</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="cidade-uf" size="100" type="text" value=" " /></p>
        <p><span style="color: #283649; font-size: 14px;">Telefone*</span></p>
        <p><input maxlength="100" name="telefone" size="100" type="text" value=" " /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Email Yourself" /></p>
    </form>    
</body>

</html>
```

A imagem a seguir é um exemplo de como seria se o aplicativo padrão fosse o Gmail

[image: Exemplo gmail]

Tenha em mente que esse método é limitado e não irá funcionar se o usuário não tiver um aplicativo de e-mails instalado. Sugiro que você faça como o Anderson sugeriu no comentário e utilize algum serviço de terceiros ou um serviço de e-mails próprio (se for o caso).

Comment: Muito obrigada! Você poderia me indicar algum serviço de terceiro para esse tipo de formulario?

Comment: Eu conheço o Mandrill, mas agora ele é pago https://medium.com/@i_shivendra/sending-a-mail-without-a-backend-using-js-ae15c0aec2cb

Comment: Agradeço pelo retorno .. mas a plataforma sugeriu usar o Jotform :)